# How to prove the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:|s_n-t|<\epsilon\}$ is infinite for all $\epsilon>0$ in the following case?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

If $t\in \mathbb{R}$, how to prove if there is a subsequence of $(s_n)$ converging to $t$, then the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:|s_n-t|<\epsilon\}$ is infinite for all $\epsilon>0$?

The proof given book is simply a statment "if $\lim_k s_{n_k}=t$ and $\epsilon>0$, the all but finitely many of the $n_k$'s are in $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:|s_n-t|<\epsilon\}$". However the statement doesn't quite make much sense to me.

$1.$ how does $\lim_k s_{n_k}=t$ imply infinitely many **$n_k$** are in the set of $|s_n-t|<\epsilon$?

$2.$ our goal is to prove  infiniteness, but the proof says "all but finitely" and I intepret it as almost all but not all are infinite, which doesn't satisfy our goal.

Could someone please explain the proof?

Comment: Write down the definition of a limit of a sequence, it should help. For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N\in\mathbb N$ such that whenever $n\ge N$ we have, etc.

Comment: There are two kinds of infinity in $\mathbb{N}$: The one that leaves out a finite number of naturals, e.g. $\{100,101,102,103,....\}$, and the one that leaves out an infinite number of naturals, e.g.: $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$(although there are much more complicated examples).

Comment: Regarding point 2., if the set of those $n\in N$ that DON'T satisfy something is  a finite set then the set of those $n\in N$ that DO satisfy it is an infinite set

Answer (score 0):

If the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:|s_n-t|<\epsilon\}$ is finite, let 
$$
m=\max\{n\in\mathbb{N}:|s_n-t|\}.
$$
Then, for $n>m$ you have that $|s_n-t|\geq\epsilon$. So the sequence does not converge to $t$.

Another way to see it is that by definition of limit, there exists $n_0$ such that $|s_n-t|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

Comment: I guess my concern is how do we get from subsequence $s_{n_k}$ to the limit definition of the original sequence

Comment: You mean this? $$\{n_k\in\mathbb{N}:|s_{n_k}-t|<\epsilon\}\subset\{n\in\mathbb{N}:|s_n-t|<\epsilon\}.$$

Comment: Yes. how do we show this?

Comment: It's obvious. All the indices of the subsequence are some of the indices of the sequence.